# Split every first three digit

Tags: algorithm

I have code  like that "010200345"

i  want  split every first three digit

please  help to solve this question

Thanks kapil

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? What language are you using?

Comment: example of output will also clarify.  do you want 010, 200, 345 or simply 0, 2, 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of my projects:

```
String.prototype.chunk = function(n) {
    if(this.length > 0) {
        n = typeof n == 'undefined' ? 2 : n;
        return this.match(new RegExp('.{1,'+n+'}','g'));
    } else return [];
};
```

You can then use something like this:

```
var parts = String(num).chunk(3); // parts as array
```

Comment: wow.  seems like a common thing!  wonder why I haven't had to write this at all!